# Automake on mac does not work

Tags: macos, automake

When I clone the automake code from github:

https://github.com/raywill/automake

With the demo code run
./build.sh init

The problem comes out :

It says like the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either investigating [homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) if you need to install OSS on OS X.

They make the process of installing an maintaining open source tools much easier on the Mac.

If you need to build this from the repo directly, then please give a better explanation in your question of what you have tried to do to resolve this problem so far.